# Warning: Failed prop type error in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I took this error : Invalid prop `age` supplied to `User`.
at User (http://localhost:3000/main.46b6535cc35ca7137599.hot-update.js:27:5)

**My Code in App.js file :**

```
import User from './components/User.js';
import React from "react";

function App() {
return (
<>
<User
  name="Emir"
  surname="Demirgezer"
  isLoggedIn={true}
  age="20"
  friends = {["Ayşe","Fatma","Hayriye","Haydi","Çiftetelliye"]}
/>
</>
);
}

export default App;
```

**My code in User.js File:**

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function User ({name,surname,age, isLoggedIn, friends}) {
return(
    <>
        <h1>
            {isLoggedIn ? `${name} ${surname} (${age})`: "Giriş Yapmadınız."}
        </h1>

          {
          friends.map((friend)=>
            <div key={friend.id}>{friend}</div>
        )
        }
    </>
);
}

User.propTypes = {
name : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
surname: PropTypes.string, 
isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool,
age: PropTypes.oneOfType([ // OneOfType birden fazla property tipi vermek istiyorsak kullanıyoruz
  PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number
]),  
friends: PropTypes.array,
};

export default User;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-kepler-jrg699?file=/src/User.jsx

Answer (score -1):

'React' must be in scope when using JSX. Just Import React in User.js file

```
import React from 'react'
```

Comment: Not since v17 ~ https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#removing-unused-react-imports

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).